# how do I change the dimensions of several selected identical objects - como altero as dimensões de vários objetos iguais selecionados

Tags: dimensions

quando seleciono vários e modifico ele altera só de 1 objeto / When I select several and modify it, it only changes 1 object[image: imagem da dúvida]

Answer (score 0):

You can change the *Scale* instead of the *Dimensions*, press <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>LMB</kbd> on the value, change the value and press <kbd>Enter</kbd>, all the objects will change their scale and therefore their dimension, at last apply the scale with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>A</kbd>.

But maybe you should rethink the way you've worked your objects. For an object that is repeated like this, maybe you should use a modifier like *Array*, or use *Instancing*, or use Geometry Nodes, or use linked duplications (duplicate your object with <kbd>Alt</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> instead of <kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>D</kbd> so that they share the same mesh).

For the latter, you can still link all the objects: do the dimension changes on one object only, apply the scale, select all the other objects, shift select the one that has been edited, press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>L</kbd> > *Link Object Data*.

Comment: Try holding down the Alt key while modifying the value.

Comment: the Dimensions values?

Comment: Worth a try although I must admit I hadn't tried it when I posted my comment. In fact it only modifies the last selected object unfortunately. :^(

Comment: Yes it makes sense as each object may have different dimensions